# Xades4J Error on validating a signature: Verification failed for property 'SigningCertificate': Property contains too many certificates

Tags: xades4j

When I validate a signature, that I have created before using the same keystore (and XA), the following exception arises:

> Verification failed for property 'SigningCertificate': SigningCertificate property contains one or more certificates that are not part of the certification path.

I'm using the following cert-chain:

1. root-CA (globalsign),
2. intermediate certificate
3. company certificate
4. project certificate

All certificate are stored in the used keystore.

However, when trying the same thing with a self-signed certificate, only it worked, I just needed to put the certificate in the certs-and-crls-directory, too.

**KeyingDataProvider:**

```
new FileSystemKeyStoreKeyingDataProvider(KeyStore.getDefaultType(),
    "D:\...\signing.keystore", 
    new FirstCertificateSelector(),
    new DirectStorePasswordProvider("pass"),
    new DirectKeyPasswordProvider("pass"), true);
```

**CertificateValidationProvider:**

```
FileSystemDirectoryCertStore certStore = new FileSystemDirectoryCertStore("D:\...\certs");
CertificateValidationProvider certValidator = new PKIXCertificateValidationProvider(
        loadKeystore(), 
        false, // should be true, when validation works.
        certStore.getStore());

private KeyStore loadKeystore() {
    // deleted exception handling for readability, here
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    FileInputStream keystoreInStream = new FileInputStream("D:\...\verification.keystore");
    keyStore.load(keystoreInStream, "pass".toCharArray());
    return keyStore;
}
```

**Feedback on keystores**

The signing-keystore contains all 4 certificates. The verification-keystore contains the root-certificate (globalsign-root-ca), only. The certs-directory contains all certificates but the root (globalsign-root-ca). Then I get the following error:

> Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
>   unable to find valid certification path to requested target

When using the same keystore as for signing (a file-system-copy) then I get the error:

> Caused by:
>   xades4j.verification.SigningCertificateCertsNotInCertPathException:
>   Verification failed for property 'SigningCertificate':
>   SigningCertificate property contains one or more certificates that are
>   not part of the certification path.

Comment: Please provide some more info. How are you creating the KeyingDataProvider for signature production and the CertificateValidationProvider for signature validation?

Comment: @lgoncalves: I amended my question with this information.

Comment: the key-entry on signing.keystore contains the full chain? Which certificates are contained on verification.keystore? (only root-CA should ne needed here, as long as the "certs" folder contains all the other certificates) The code looks ok... and there are some tests on the lib that use certification paths with intermediate CAs. Maybe you can send me some test program with your code?

Comment: @lgoncalves I amended my question with info on the keystores. When I open the signing-certificate (Nr. 4 in question) in Windows, I don't see the certification-path, only the current certificate. Do you think that could be the problem? BTW: what format do the certs need to be (PEM, DER, ...)?

Comment: Is certificate number 4 the only one stored on a PrivateKeyEntry? Which certificate references are present on the SigningCertificate property? The configuration of your keystores seems to be ok.. We have to find this one!

Comment: For signing: yes, #4 is the only stored as type _PrivateKeyEntry_, #1-3 are of type _trustedCertEntry_. There are 4 entries in the _SigningCertificate_ element, but only their issuer is stated in a readable form, so I did not check if the digest value is correct. For verification: only #1 is stored in the keystore, #2-4 are .cer files.

Comment: Since you have 4 entries in the SigningCertificate property, the PrivateKeyEntry for certificate #4 has to include the certification chain. Do those 4 entries appear to be as expected, based on the issuer names? On the verification keystore, #1 is stored as a TrustedCertEntry?

Comment: The error you're getting when using the signing-keystore for verification is due to the fact that all the entries except #4 are TrustedCertEntries. This means that the cert path builder will stop on the first trusted CA it gets (#3 for instance) and the corresponding cert path doesn't match the one in the SigningCertificate property. That behavior is correct having in mind that the signing-keystore configuration is not suitable for verification.

Comment: The (only) entry in the verification-keystore is the root-CA (#1) and is of type _trustedCertEntry_. All 4 entries in the _SigningCertificate_ element seem to be correct, despite one aspect: within _IssuerSerial_ there is the _X509IssuerName_ of the certificate's **issuer**, but the _X509SerialNumber_ of the **certificate**! Is that correct (the parent element suggests it's the serial of the issuer)?

Comment: That's correct. The issuer name and serial number can be used to identify a certificate. I'm running out of ideas here. Can you send me the signature and the .cer files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out (i.e. a colleague helped me to).
The certificate/key (#3), I used to sign my self-created keypair (#4) with, was not allowed to sign other certificates. Although creating the signature was possible without any error, I got the error message `unable to find valid certification path to requested target` when verifying the signature, which was pretty misleading.

As a 'solution', I only used certificates #1-3, and used the private key of #3 to create the signature.

@lgoncalves thanks for your enduring help.

P.S.: I get the same error message with my working setup, when I configure CRLs enabled, but do not provide all of them (i.e. one CRL issued by #2 and one issued by #1, when verifying a signature generated with #3).